# isolate function with reactive object base on dplyr shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I created a simple shiny app. The goal is to create a `histogram` with options to manipulate the plot for each dataset. The problem is that when I change a dataset application first show me empty plot and then present  a correct plot. To understand the problem I add `renderText` which show me a number of rows in `getDataParams` dataset. It seems to me that `isolate` function should be a solution but I tried several configurations, apparently I still do not understand this function.

```
library(lazyeval)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)
data(diamonds)

ui <- fluidPage(
      column(3,
             selectInput("data", "", choices = c('', 'iris', 'diamonds')),
             uiOutput('server_cols'),
             uiOutput("server_cols_fact"),
             uiOutput("server_params")
      ),
      column(9,
             plotOutput("plot"),
             textOutput('text')

      )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
      data <- reactive({
            switch(input$data, diamonds = diamonds, iris = iris)
      })

      output$server_cols <- renderUI({
            validate(need(input$data != "", "Firstly select a dataset."))
            data <- data()
            nam <- colnames(data)
            selectInput('cols', "Choose numeric columns:", choices = nam[sapply(data, function(x) is.numeric(x))])
      })

      output$server_cols_fact <- renderUI({

            req(input$data)

            data <- data(); nam <- colnames(data)
            selectizeInput('cols_fact', "Choose a fill columns:",
                           choices = nam[sapply(data, function(x) is.factor(x))])
      })

      output$server_params <- renderUI({

            req(input$cols_fact)

            data <- isolate(data()); col_nam <- input$cols_fact
            params_vec <- unique(as.character(data[[col_nam]]))
            selectizeInput('params', "Choose arguments of fill columns:", choices = params_vec,
                           selected = params_vec, multiple = TRUE)

      })

      getDataParams <- reactive({

            df <- isolate(data())
            factor_col <- input$cols_fact
            col_diverse <- eval(factor_col)

            criteria <- interp(~col_diverse %in% input$params, col_diverse = as.name(col_diverse))
            df <- df %>%
                  filter_(criteria) %>%
                  mutate_each_(funs(factor), factor_col)
      })

      output$text <- renderText({
            if(!is.null(input$cols)) {
                  print(nrow(getDataParams()))
            }
      })
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
            if (!is.null(input$cols)) {

                  var <- eval(input$cols)
                  print('1')

                  diversifyData <- getDataParams()
                  factor_col <- input$cols_fact
                  print('2')

                  plot <- ggplot(diversifyData, aes_string(var, fill = diversifyData[[factor_col]])) +
                        geom_histogram(color = 'white', binwidth = 1)

                  print('3')
            }
            plot

      })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer that features quite minimal changes and gives probably some deeper insights into how to control reactivity in future projects.

Your program logic features some decisions of the kind "do A if B, but not if C". But it approaches them brutally, by repeating "do A if B" until finally "not C" is true. To be more precise: You want your `getDataParams` to be renewed (action A) if `input$cols` changes (action B), but it throws errors if `input$params` has not changed yet (condition C).

Okay, now to the fix: We use a feature of `observeEvent` to evaluate if `getDataParams` should be recalculated. Lets read ([source](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observeEvent.html)):

> Both observeEvent and eventReactive take an ignoreNULL parameter that
>   affects behavior when the eventExpr evaluates to NULL (or in the
>   special case of an actionButton, 0). In these cases, if ignoreNULL is
>   TRUE, then an observeEvent will not execute and an eventReactive will
>   raise a silent validation error.

So the change is basically one command. Change

```
getDataParams <- reactive({ ... })
```

to

```
getDataParams <- eventReactive({
    if(is.null(input$params) || !(input$cols_fact %in% colnames(data()))){
      NULL
    }else{
      if(all(input$params %in% data()[[input$cols_fact]])){
        1
      }else{
        NULL
      }
    }, { ... }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
```

Here we check if `input$cols_fact` is a valid column name and if `input$params` has already been assigned and if so, we check if `input$params` is a valid list of factors for the given column. This feature was mainly designed, I suppose, to check if some element exists (`input$something` returning `NULL` if it's not defined), but we abuse it for logic evaluation and return `NULL` in one case and `1` (or something not `NULL`) in the other.

In contrast to logical tests inside the reactive environment, `getDataReactive` won't be changed or won't trigger change events at all, if the condition is not met.

Note: This is the minimal solution I found. With this tool and/or other changes, the code can still be fairly improved.

Full Code below.

Greetings!

```
library(lazyeval)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)
data(diamonds)

ui <- fluidPage(
      column(3,
             selectInput("data", "", choices = c('', 'iris', 'diamonds')),
             uiOutput('server_cols'),
             uiOutput("server_cols_fact"),
             uiOutput("server_params")
      ),
      column(9,
             plotOutput("plot"),
             textOutput('text')

      )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
      data <- reactive({
            switch(input$data, diamonds = diamonds, iris = iris)
      })

      output$server_cols <- renderUI({
            validate(need(input$data != "", "Firstly select a dataset."))
            data <- data()
            nam <- colnames(data)
            selectInput('cols', "Choose numeric columns:", choices = nam[sapply(data, function(x) is.numeric(x))])
      })

      output$server_cols_fact <- renderUI({

            req(input$data)

            data <- data(); nam <- colnames(data)
            selectizeInput('cols_fact', "Choose a fill columns:",
                           choices = nam[sapply(data, function(x) is.factor(x))])
      })

      output$server_params <- renderUI({

            req(input$cols_fact)

            data <- isolate(data()); col_nam <- input$cols_fact
            params_vec <- unique(as.character(data[[col_nam]]))
            selectizeInput('params', "Choose arguments of fill columns:", choices = params_vec,
                           selected = params_vec, multiple = TRUE)

      })

      getDataParams <- eventReactive({
        if(is.null(input$params) || !(input$cols_fact %in% colnames(data()))){
          NULL
        }else{
          if(all(input$params %in% data()[[input$cols_fact]])){
            1
          }else{
            NULL
          }
        }, { 
            df <- isolate(data())
            factor_col <- input$cols_fact
            col_diverse <- eval(factor_col)

            criteria <- interp(~col_diverse %in% input$params, col_diverse = as.name(col_diverse))
            df <- df %>%
                  filter_(criteria) %>%
                  mutate_each_(funs(factor), factor_col)
      }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)

      output$text <- renderText({
            if(!is.null(input$cols)) {
                  print(nrow(getDataParams()))
            }
      })
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
            if (!is.null(input$cols)) {

                  var <- eval(input$cols)
                  print('1')

                  diversifyData <- getDataParams()
                  factor_col <- input$cols_fact
                  print('2')

                  plot <- ggplot(diversifyData, aes_string(var, fill = diversifyData[[factor_col]])) +
                        geom_histogram(color = 'white', binwidth = 1)

                  print('3')
            }
            plot

      })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

To best explaining the flow - I create a picture that explain how the plot get refresh as below:

- So, with no isolate code, you will any change in any change on any control on the code will trigger the change to the control on the end of arrow. In this case which end up result the plot refresh 5 times.
- With the isolate code in your code from above post, you already eliminate two small arrow.
- To avoid the case you mentioned with when **Choose a fill columns**, you need to eliminate the big arrow that I highlighted by isolate the `input$cols_fact` in `output$plot <- renderPlot{...}` reactive.
- With this you still have the plot refresh two time when choose data table but I think it acceptable as you need the plot to re-active when you do **Choose numeric columns**

Hope this answer your questions! Having fun playing arround with Shiny!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But actually I try to find a solution which solve this problem entirely, hence current situation is not acceptable.

Comment: Another way to look at it is cut of all the link to plot and use action button to refresh the graph though this will be less interactive with small data but better performance and view for data that big and calculations time would take up to 10s